# gmp unit tests failing on Ventura Mac m1

Tags: apple-m1, gmp, macos-ventura

I am running Mac OS Ventura (13.0) on M1 Pro chipset.

I am successfully compiling GMP version 6.2.1, but most of unit tests are failing.

Either with

> Segmentation fault: 11

or with

> Abort trap: 6

```
Version:           GNU MP 6.2.1
Host type:         aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0
ABI:               64
Install prefix:    /usr/local
Compiler:          gcc
Static libraries:  yes
Shared libraries:  yes

============================================================================
Testsuite summary for GNU MP 6.2.1
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 50
# PASS:  14
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  36
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============
```

Example:

```
../../test-driver: line 107: 36102 Segmentation fault: 11  "$@" > $log_file 2>&1
FAIL: t-toom22
../../test-driver: line 107: 36121 Abort trap: 6           "$@" > $log_file 2>&1
```

Comment: First thing to try would be the latest snapshot from https://gmplib.org/download/snapshot/gmp-next/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the build and tests are broken on macOS Ventura only. Luckily, according to my tests there is **no need to go to the "unstable master branch" or snapshots** but you can apply a specific patch (from gmplib!) to the official GMP 6.2.1 source tree.

https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/raw-rev/5f32dbc41afc

The same patch is also used by Homebrew to build gmp on macOS Ventura. See in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gmp.rb